# Can Someone help me with this underscore appearing in the download link

Tags: php, html, href

Below is my code a simple href with php code:

```
<a href="<?php echo $xmlfilepath;?>" title="Download File" id="no-link" download="<?php echo 'Smartpost_' . $uploadedfilename; ?>" >
    <input type="button" name="download" value="Download File" style="color:white;background-color:green;font-family:courier">
</a>
```

[image: Ghost Underscore Appreating]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code:

```
 echo '<a href="'.$xmlfilepath.'" title="Download File" id="no-link" download="Smartpost_'.$uploadedfilename.'" style="color:white;background-color:green;font-family:courier">Download</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

What looks like an underscore is actually a "linked"/underlined whitespace/newline. In your code remove any newlines:

```
<a href="<?php echo $xmlfilepath;?>" title="Download File" id="no-link" download="<?php echo 'Smartpost_' . $uploadedfilename; ?>" ><input type="button" name="download" value="Download File" style="color:white;background-color:green;font-family:courier"></a>
```

**Important:**

Since `<input>` is invalid in `<a>`, replace the `<input>` with regular text and use CSS to make the link *look like* a button:

```
<a class="button" href="<?php echo $xmlfilepath;?>" title="Download File" id="no-link" download="<?php echo 'Smartpost_' . $uploadedfilename; ?>">Download File</a>
```

CSS example (adjust to suit your needs):

```
a.button {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```